# How to substitute a string to current timestamp in mod_substitute apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, httpserver

I would like to substitute a string by the current timestamp in milliseconds, like

```
   Substitute s|MyString|timestamp|ni
```

How can I do it using **mod_substitute.c** inside my **.htaccess** file ?

Comment: Do you really need milliseconds? Wiil just a number seconds since the Epoch suffice?

Comment: I guess it would suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a combination of substitute and ssi include, but it works

```
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html                                                   
Substitute 's/magical-string-here/<!--#config timefmt="%s" --><!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->/'

Options +Includes                                                                            
AddType text/html .php      # or what have you                                                                      
AddOutputFilterByType INCLUDES text/html
```

Comment: I am a newbie with apache configuration. Do I need some escape chars? Because if I leave the single quote it does nothing and if I remove it i have a server error. Only for this substitute

Comment: I meant it replaces with empty string rather than timestamp

Comment: Which apache version are you using? Do you have server-side include module on? Make sure you add proper file type in `AddType text/html .php`

Comment: running Apache 2.4 with XAMP

Comment: %s comes from strftime(3). Try `man strftime` for the list of available formats. Mine has %s and it is a number of seconds since the Epoch

Comment: well, indeed it works on different configs. My Mac has MAMP running Apache and it works perfectly. So I'll mark it as valid :)

Comment: the answer would be even more correct by replacing text/html by application/x-httpd-php. In fact, with the config on my Mac it wouldnot render php anymore had I left text/html.